# Django - SocialAuth login without leaving the page

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, openid, django-socialauth

I'm using the nice [`django-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) in one of my projects.

Basically I would like to be able to login without leaving the current page (whithout even refreshing it).

I thought about simply using `target="_blank"` in my provider links

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin service %}"
  rel="nofollow" target="_blank">{{ service|title }}</a>
```

But of course it is redirecting to the default location after the successful login.
Is there a way to automatically close this new window on success so the user gets the previous page ?

Comment: Note that [`python-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) is the one we should use now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some JS and some parameters for the backend, you could open a popup window where the user can do the auth (some backends accept parameters that generate a different auth dialog layout). In that popup the user will proceed with the auth process and the popup could be closed with some JS too when the user is redirected back to the final URL.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your great app :) I'll try this out.

Comment: I simply specified the `next` url and added the autoclose js. It works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the services support javascript based login, which might be what your are looking for, however it depends on which services you want to use and whether they do support this. For example there is [Client-side JavaScript SDK on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/).

Comment: Thank you. I saw this SDK for Facebook, this would be the best if I were using only Facebook. But I was trying to find a way to manage it more globally with a SocialAuth kind of close_the_window_instead_of_redirect_on_success setting :)